# How to prevent 'develop' from beeing merged into 'release'?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

We're using GitFlow and have several branches (develop, release/x.xx and master). We create release/x.xx branch from develop in a week before release. This week we work on 2 versions: we do bugfix (in release) and develop new features (in develop). The normal flow is to make a branch from develop and then merge it back to develop or to make a branch from release and then merge it back to release. But sometimes the developers forget this and accidentally make a branch from develop and merge it into release... We need some protection from such accidental merges.  What is the best way to prevent such a merge (develop -> feature -> release)?

We've got version.data file in repository and it's different in develop and release branches. Maybe writing some server-side hook that allows to change version.data only in develop will solve the problem?

We use GitLab Community edition as a git server.

Comment: Do you use some repository management tool like GitLab or GitHub? Merge/Pull requests are a very effective way to prevent "accidental" merges into wrong branches. If you realize a branch was created from a wrong source branch, you can still rebase onto the correct source branch.

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes we make a feature-branch from develop and then merge it into the release

Since the feature branch will be merged into release, the simple solution would be to create it *from* release. Do you merge the release branch back to develop after a release has happened? I suppose you do, since you want your bugfixes in develop, so the feature will find its way into develop eventually.

You could consider adding the `version.data` file to gitignore, to prevent it from being overridden in a merge.

Comment: The normal flow is to make a branch from develop and then merge it back to develop or to make a branch from release and then merge it back to release. But sometimes the developers forget this and accidentally make a branch from develop and merge it into release... We need some protection from such accidental merges.